# Pass JNIEnv or Context from Java to Go

Tags: android, go, jnienv, gomobile

I've successfully written a go mobile library and used it from an Android Java app.

I've also successfully called a c function from JNI. This one has the JNIEnv pointer.

**I'd like to pass the context/JNIEnv from Java to Go.**

Here's where it seems to get complicated:

1. Go Mobile does not seem to use JNIEnv at all.
2. LoadJNI.java does have a context object and claims to pass it to the Go side. But there it isn't visible.
3. I've been able to include jni.h using the "C" directive
4. I can transfer the JNIEnv from JNI/C or store it there as a global variable but that's an ugly kludge.
5. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16876 talks about a proposal to do reverse binding but it's unclear what the status is.
6. https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind also talks about it but the following code snippet

`import "Java/java/lang/System"
 t := System.CurrentTimeMillis()`

returns

```
cannot find package "Java/java/lang/System" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/Java/java/lang/System (from $GOROOT)
/Users/----/go/src/Java/java/lang/System (from $GOPATH)
```

In C I solved it with a compiler directive: #cgo CFLAGS: -I...

But I'm not sure how to do it for Java

In short, I'm now stuck and would appreciate help. Ideally, I'd just like to pass the object as a parameter, if possible. However, I'd settle for any reverse binding to call Java from Go.

Comment: This may be of interest   https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile

Comment: The reverse binding code from the `gobind` doc should be compiled using the `gomobile` tool and not the Go compiler directly.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question, but I'd hate someone to go through this as well too. I'll update this answer as I go along.

**Basic Setup**

Edit build.gradle and add GOPATH and GO to gobind (additions in bold):

```
gobind {
    pkg = ".../reverse/reverse"
    GOPATH = "/Users/johndoe/go"
    GO = "/usr/local/go/bin"
}
```

**How to develop**

1. Start from the reverse example. Get it to compile and run.
2. Make one modification and recompile.

**Missing gobind**

It turns out the installation process neglected to build gobind. Run `go install golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind`

**I'm Stuck**

Trying to modify the reverse project to do anything other than what it's already doing is failing. Even stuff like passing an object and calling toString will fail.

More to come...

Comment: I have the same problem. Where is the build.gradle? It is binding from golang project right ? Why there is a build.gradle file for binding?

Comment: I was sure this was a dead project, but I just checked and it's very much alive. I think your best bet is the github project page or a new question.

Comment: For now, I think I'll just wait for any other working example. I already have another workaround for my problem, so don't really need to use reverse bind for now.